# Angular lazy-loading not accepting more than one child route to have param

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I'm designing a basic ionic app, my app has multiple child component with lazy loading feature.the thing is when more than one child route has parameter in the URL means it is not routing it.

If I have a single route with param means it is working fine.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { PlacesPage } from './places.page';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: 'tabs',
      component: PlacesPage,
      children: [
        {
        path: 'discover',
        children: [
        {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: './discover/discover.module#DiscoverPageModule'
        },
        {
            path: ':placeId',
            loadChildren: './discover/place-detail/place-detail.module#PlaceDetailPageModule'
        }

        ]
    },
    {
        path: 'offer',
        children: [
            {
                path: 'edit/:placeId',
                loadChildren:
                  './offer/edit-offer/edit-offer.module#EditOfferPageModule'
              }
            ,
            {
                path: '',
                loadChildren: './offer/offer.module#OfferPageModule'
            },
            {
                path: ':placeId',
                loadChildren: './offer/offer-bookings/offer-bookings.module#OfferBookingsPageModule'
            },

            {
                path: 'new',
                loadChildren: './offer/new-offer/new-offer.module#NewOfferPageModule'
            }
        ]

    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/places/tabs/discover',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    }

      ]
    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/places/tabs/discover',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    }
  ];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class PlacesRoutingModule {}
```

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'outlets' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'outlets' of null
    at createNewSegmentGroup

Comment: Second child route put in your page.module.ts, there make code to redirect your first-page child. you can see the same example in ionic tabs template.

Comment: what do i need to change?